# error when sync with google-calendar

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am working on an application to sync with google calendar, I got the following error:

> Error refreshing the OAuth2 token,
>
> message: '{
>         "error" : "unauthorized_client",
>         "error_description" : "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method."
>       }'

Comment: While the error message alone may be understandable to some of us its best that you edit your question and include your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a project on Google Developer console there are several types of clients you can create.

Browser clients are used for web applications,  Native clients are used for installed applications,  Service account clients are used for background applications mostly.

The authentication code used to use each type of client is different.  You cant use the code for native applications with a web application or you will get the following error.

> Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method.

**Solution** figure out what type of application you are trying to make.  Then make sure you created the corect client type on Google Developer console and are using the code designed for that client type.